# String does not match expected pattern d3 select

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I am using d3 v5 for data visualization, I have created a force layout with each of the nodes having their own name as id. This part is done dynamically. 
The HTML part works fine , the **userInput.value** will return me an id with "/" in it (The ID for the node in this case is "foo/A" ). However the d3.select function fails when selecting an ID value with forward slash in it.
Is there a way to bypass this error without renaming all the nodes?

```
var userInput = document.getElementById("targetNode");
  var theNode = d3.select("#" + userInput.value);
```

Comment: Just write a loop function that removes all the `'/'` from the values. Easiest way I see to get around it.

Comment: Then there might be multiple nodes having same name.

Comment: Are there mulitples with the same name while the `'/'` is present?

Comment: There could be 2 different names like A/B and AB, both will result in the same id. (I do not have control over the node names)

Comment: Ah ok I see. I didn't know the `'/'` could be in between the words. What error is it displaying?

Comment: It says "String does not match pattern"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to escape the `/` with `\\`. So doing something like this should not return an error:

```
var userInput = document.getElementById("targetNode");
var temp = userInput.value;
var temp2 = temp.replace('/','\\/')
var theNode = d3.select("#" + temp2);
```

Comment: Worked, Thank you.
Needed to escape every character as I learned javascript only replaces the first occurrence , I edited your code a bit to this
`var temp2 = temp.replace(/[/]/g, "\\/");`

Comment: Nice, Glad I could help. Would you mind throwing me an upvote? I'll do the same

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Forgot that